# SuSE : ZYPP repositories

Tags: repository, suse, zypper

I'm currently using SuSE Enterprise Linux 10.3 , may I know where to find a list of valid repositories.

I'm trying to upgrade the glibc in it.. I read it is not recommended.

Comment: Is 10.3 still supported? I fear not.

Comment: I don't think so but still I wish to try and upgrade the glibc in it.. I read it is not recommended.